# Concatenate column names in sql select statement if certain condition is met

Tags: sql, concatenation

I have a SQL `SELECT` statement pulling 4 columns:

```
SELECT cmm_residence, cmm_packing, cmm_furniture, cmm_overage
```

These columns are simple no/yes values (0,1). I need an additional column `Description` to concatenate any 'Yes' values for that row.

For example: if the query returned 'Yes' for `cmm_residence` and `cmm_furniture`, the `Description` column should be `cmm_residence,cmm_furniture`.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is the issue/problem on your query?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: I understood how the Concat function worked, I just couldn't wrap my head around getting the function to utlize Case.  Another user below helped give me some clarity.  Still fumbling my way through learning SQL.  Thanks for responding, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table  mytable (cmm_residence varchar(5), cmm_packing varchar(5), cmm_furniture varchar(5), cmm_overage varchar(5));
 insert into mytable values('yes','no','no','yes');
 insert into mytable values('no','no','no','yes');
 insert into mytable values('yes','yes','no','yes');
```

Query:

```
 select cmm_residence, cmm_packing, cmm_furniture, cmm_overage,
 concat(case when cmm_residence='yes' then ' cmm_residence ,'end,
 case when cmm_packing='yes' then ' cmm_packing ,'end,
 case when cmm_furniture='yes' then ' cmm_furniture ,'end,
 case when cmm_overage='yes' then ' cmm_overage 'end)Description
 from mytable
```

Output:

| cmm_residence | cmm_packing | cmm_furniture | cmm_overage | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | no | no | yes | cmm_residence , cmm_overage |
| no | no | no | yes | cmm_overage |
| yes | yes | no | yes | cmm_residence , cmm_packing , cmm_overage |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ff5dec14135f4b4a9646ffb4acd9e0a)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE into your SELECT statement adding whatever logic you need like this:

```
SELECT cmm_residence, cmm_packing, cmm_furniture, cmm_overage, 
CASE
    WHEN cmm_residence = 1 THEN 'cmm_residence'
    WHEN  cmm_packing = 1  THEN 'cmm_packing'
    ELSE ''
END As 'Description' 
FROM Table
```

Just add as much cases with logic as you want, take into account this isn't quite performant query.